# Using RAW() in Camel 3 endpoint DSL

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I have a set of FTP endpoints in a Camel application I recently migrated to Camel 3, but I am struggling with password encoding.

I have some passwords that contain special characters like `+`, and in the past I was able to have Camel connect to these FTP accounts by specifying the endpoint as `ftp://user@host/path?password=RAW(password)`.

However, I now want to declare these routes with the new Endpoint DSL, like this:

```
ftp(host:port/path).username(user).password(password)
```

And this way the special characters in my passwords are URL encoded and thus fail to login.

Is there a way to replicate the behavior of using RAW() in the new Endpoint DSL?

Comment: Ah yeah its something that we may miss out - I have created a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-15015

And you have tried using .password("RAW(xxxx)") as the string ought to be used as-is.

Comment: Yep I tried and I seem to remember it wasn't working, I'll have another look.

Comment: Okay have a fix in the works for Camel 3.3.0 onwards.

Comment: Camel 3.4.0 LTS fixes this. Yaay! [Release notes](https://camel.apache.org/releases/release-3.4.0/)